# В течение какого времени происходит обновление цены приложение в каталоге Google Play?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

В течение какого времени происходит обновление цены приложение в каталоге Google Play после ее изменения в Google Play Console?

Я изменил цену - она поменялась в каталоге в течение нескольких минут.

Я изменил ее еще раз. Она уже так быстро не поменялась! А прошло уже более часа.

Есть какие-то регламенты на эту операцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update your apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en):

> App updates take some time to be delivered to existing users. If
>   you’ve submitted an update that hasn’t showed up on Google Play,
>   please wait at least 24 hours before contacting our support team.

До 24 часов.